# Accessing all TeX Live documentation files in Kile

Tags: documentation, kile, texdoc

I have set the location of TeX documentation as `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/doc` in Kile and selected the option of 'Use your system's TeXLive documentation'. Still, when I go to Help -> TeX Documentation -> Documentation Browser, I cannot access the documentation for all the packages installed on my system, just a few of them. How do I access all the documentation files?

Comment: I don't actually know if kile uses texdoc for that or not, but does texdoc work from the command line? Are you using texlive installed from the installer from TUG, or are you using the texlive packages of your (presumably linux) distribution? If I install texlive from the Archlinux repos, for example, it doesn't include most of the documentation.

Comment: @frabjous I can access all the documentation using texdoc from the command line. I have installed texlive from the installer from TUG. Yes, I am on Linux (Manjaro). I thought that since Kile asks for the location of TeX documentation, it uses the files located there. I cannot 'browse' the documentation using texdoc, I want something to do that, possibly the .dtx and .tex files as well which are used to generate the documentation pdf files.

Comment: I know this is not the question, but in case you don't already know it, `texdoctk` can help for browsing available documentation.